# Как перемешать массив?

Tags: c#, массивы

Нужно перемешать массив.

Класс Program:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Poker
{

    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            Deck d = new Deck();
            d.PrintCards();
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Класс Deck:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Poker
{
    class Deck
    {
        string[] ranks = new string[13];
        string[] suits = new string[4];

        public Card[] cards = new Card[52];

        public Deck()
        {
            for (int a = 0; a < 13; a++)
            {
                for (int b = 0; b < 4; b++)
                {
                    cards[b * 13 + a] = new Card();
                    cards[b * 13 + a].Rank = a;
                    cards[b * 13 + a].Suit = b;
                }
            }
            ranks[0] = "2";
            ranks[1] = "3";
            ranks[2] = "4";
            ranks[3] = "5";
            ranks[4] = "6";
            ranks[5] = "7";
            ranks[6] = "8";
            ranks[7] = "9";
            ranks[8] = "10";
            ranks[9] = "J";
            ranks[10] = "Q";
            ranks[11] = "K";
            ranks[12] = "A";
            suits[0] = "c";
            suits[1] = "h";
            suits[2] = "s";
            suits[3] = "d";
        }

        public void ShuffleDeck()
        {
            int x;
            Card tempcard;

            for (int a = 0; a < 52; a++)
            {
                Random rand = new Random();
                x = rand.Next(1, 100);
                tempcard = cards[a];
                cards[a] = cards[x];
                cards[x] = tempcard;
            }
        }

        public void PrintCards()
        {
            for (int a = 0; a < 52; a++)
            {
                Console.Write(ranks[cards[a].Rank] + suits[cards[a].Suit] + " ");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

В методе `ShuffleDeck` должно быть перемешивание колоды, но оно не работает.

Comment: Возможно, пробрасывается исключение, о котором вы "забыли" упомянуть? Например, `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` из-за того, что `x` принимает значения от 1 до 100, в то время как в `cards` всего 52 элемента.

Comment: А ещё стоит избавиться от "магических констант" `4`, `13` и `52`, разбросанных по коду. Да, вряд ли у вас когда-то будет не 4 масти по 13 карт в каждой, но хороший стиль программирования никто не отменял.

Comment: В каком смысле? У меня на консоль выводится колода только 2с, 3с, 4с, и так далее. Вот это надо перемешать только.

Answer (score 2):

Ваша реализация алгоритма обращается к массиву по случайному индексу от 0 до 99. В то время как в массиве всего 52 элемента. Будет падать. Не падает только потому, что, метод `ShuffleDeck` у вас вообще никогда не вызывается.

Стандатный способ перемешивания массива - это [Тасование Фишера–Йетса](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%A4%D0%B8%D1%88%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%E2%80%93%D0%99%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D0%B0)

```
static class RandomExtensions
{
    public static void Shuffle<T>(this Random rng, T[] array)
    {
        int n = array.Length;
        while (n > 1)
        {
            int k = rng.Next(n--);
            T temp = array[n];
            array[n] = array[k];
            array[k] = temp;
        }
    }
}
```

использовать как

```
var rand = new Random();
rand.Shuffle(cards);
```

Судя по всему, именно его вы пытались реализовать, просто чуть ошиблись с индексами.

Comment: Поскольку вопросы по перестановке элементов массива пошли косяком, создал [канонический (тм) вопросоответ](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/547996/10105).