# Как перемешать (случайно переставить) элементы в массиве?

Tags: c#

Есть данные, записанные в массив или генерируемые на лету. Как можно получить их случайную перестановку в массиве или другом контейнере?

Например: как можно получить случайную перестановку чисел от 1 до `n` в массиве/списке?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

**Обновление**: начиная с .NET 8, проще всего не изобретать велосипед, а воспользоваться встроенной функцией [`Shuffle`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.random.shuffle?view=net-8.0):

```cs
int[] data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
Random.Shared.Shuffle(data);
```

(для `List<T>` понадобится `Random.Shared.Shuffle(CollectionsMarshal.AsSpan(data));`).

Дальше рассматриваем случай, когда существующий `Shuffle` не подходит (например, у вас более младшая версия .NET, или данные поступают в потоковом виде).

---

Если у вас уже есть набор данных (массив или `List`), скорее всего вам нужно перемешивание его «на месте». Для этого подойдёт алгоритм из 3.4.2P из [TAOCP](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%98%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F), известный также как [Fisher–Yates shuffle](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%A4%D0%B8%D1%88%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%E2%80%93%D0%99%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D0%B0).

Пусть ваши данные находятся в массиве `T[] data`. Пусть `random` — экземпляр типа `Random`*. Тогда для перемешивания подходит следующий код:

```
for (int i = data.Length - 1; i >= 1; i--)
{
   int j = random.Next(i + 1);
   // обменять значения data[j] и data[i]
   var temp = data[j];
   data[j] = data[i];
   data[i] = temp;
}
```

Код очевидным образом адаптируется для случая `List<T>`.

---

Для случая, когда вам нужна не перетасовка на месте, а заполнение данными из другого источника, или данные генерируются на ходу (например, вы хотите получить перестановку чисел 1...n), можно воспользоваться немного модифицированным алгоритмом.

Если количество данных известно заранее (пусть это будет `n`), делаем так:

```
data = new T[n];
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    int j = random.Next(i + 1);
    if (j != i)
        data[i] = data[j];
    data[j] = generate(i);
}
```

Здесь `generate(i)` — выражение, которое даёт следующий, `i`-ый член исходной последовательности. Например, если данные поступают из массива `source`, то `generate(i)` — это просто `source[i]`. Если вы перемешиваете числа от 1 до `n`, это просто `i + 1`, и т. д.

Для случая, когда количество элементов не известно заранее (например, из произвольного `IEnumerable<T>`), подойдёт следующая модификация. Наш целевой контейнер должен быть `List<T>`, чтобы его можно было динамически увеличивать.

```
data = new List<T>();
foreach (var s in source)
{
    int j = random.Next(data.Length + 1);
    if (j == data.Count)
    {
        data.Add(s);
    }
    else
    {
        data.Add(data[j]);
        data[j] = s;
    }
}
```

Код основан на цитированной статье из Википедии.

---

*Если вы пользуетесь .NET Framework (но не .NET Core), не стоит создавать новый экземпляр `Random` каждый раз при выполнении этого алгоритма: это даёт большие шансы, что два раза подряд сгенерированная перестановка [будет фактически одинаковой](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter12/Random.aspx). Если ваша программа однопоточная, лучше всего создать единственный статический экземпляр `Random` в начале программы, и использовать его.

Для .NET Core этой проблемы нет, создавайте экземпляры `Random`, где вам удобнее.

Начиная с .NET 6, можно просто использовать потокобезопасный `Random.Shared`.

Comment: Уточню, что в с++ есть встроенная функция для этого, а данный алгоритм использовать нужно крайне аккуратно из-за особенностей rand() на некоторых платформах ( слишком часто в нем только 16 последних бит).

Comment: @pavel: Да, на C++ это даже в [стандартной библиотеке](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle). Но там требуется итератор произвольного доступа, так что вариант с генерацией придётся всё равно кодировать руками.

Comment: А точно `Random.Shared.Shuffle` а не просто `Random.Shuffle`?

Comment: а, все, увидел в конце про Shared

Comment: @Grundy: метод `Shuffle` в любом случае не статический, так что `Random.Shuffle` не скомпилируется.

Answer (score 4):

На взрослом https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273313/randomize-a-listt

Там победитель алгоритм, тот, что привел VladD

```
private static Random rng = new Random((int) DateTime.Now.Ticks & 0x0000FFFF);


public static void Shuffle<T>(this IList<T> list)  
{  
    int n = list.Count;  
    while (n > 1) {  
        n--;  
        int k = rng.Next(n + 1);  
        T value = list[k];  
        list[k] = list[n];  
        list[n] = value;  
    }  
}
```

Можно вспомнить БД

```
items.Select(i=> new {I=i, sort= Guid.NewGuid()}).OrderBy (i =>i.sort).Select(i=>i.I);

items.Select(i=> new {I=i, sort= rng.Next()}).OrderBy (i =>i.sort).Select(i=>i.I);
```

Comment: Первый вариант ничем не отличается от варианта в моём ответе. Вариант с rng.Next и Guid просто ужасен.

Comment: Ну почему же. Еще раз такой вариант применяется для получения случайных данных в БД в сочетании с TOP. Каждый вариант имеет право на жизнь. Главное даже в понимании. По скорости будет твой вариант быстрее, но с точки зрения понимания варианты с OrderBy вполне приемлемы. Заметь как проголосовали на взрослом сайте. Кроме того Enumerable не всегда List

Comment: @Serginio дело в том, что в SQL RAND() вызывается не больше одного  раза на строчку (по крайней мере в SQL Server). А в C# (linq to objects) нет никакой гарантии, что выражение, переданное в OrderBy, не вызовется дважды для одной строки. Т.е. можно наткнуться на кривую реализацию OrderBy, которая будет вызывать NewGuid при каждом попарном сравнении значений.

Comment: А разве ты не видел  items.Select(i=> new (I=i, sort= Guid.NewGuid())).OrderBy (i =>i.sort).Select(i=>i.I);

Comment: Кроме того, временная сложность сортировки O(N Log N), а Фишера-Ейтса O(N)

Comment: Я знаю. Я же тебе ответил в первом комментарии. Суть не в скорости. Для Linq скорость не главное, главное понимание.

Comment: Если вы ссылаетесь на «_взрослый_» сайт, вы должны бы почитать комментарии Эрика, который говорит, что `Guid` **не предназначен** выступать в роли источника случайных чисел.

Comment: `Для Linq скорость не главное` а потом программы жрут памяти раз в 1000 больше и работают не быстрее чем в 2000 году, а процессоры то мощнее стали...

Comment: @ VladD Я показал алгоритмы используемые для получения случайных данных в  БД. Посмотри сколько человек проголосовало за те предложения.

Comment: @ pavel Тогда нужно брать в руки другой язык программирования. Для большинства задач Linq выше крыши.  Для большинства задач нужна скорость и надежность разработки, а не скорость выполнения. Поверь мне программисту 1С

Comment: @Serginio: Почему количество голосов на en.SO аргумент?

Comment: Просто используют то, что людям понятно. Другое дело, что Shuffle нужно вводить как стандартный метод Linq

Comment: @Serginio на большом so за Guid отдано в 4 раза меньше голосов, чем за ФЕ. Это означает, что вариант с Guid минимум в 4 раза хуже. А если учесть его очевидную понятность, и набранные за счет этого голоса - то можно смело утверждать что он ужасен :)

Comment: @Serginio и кстати, linq появился как раз ради скорости - ради возможности отобразить запрос в базу данных, а не выполнять его, предварительно вычитав всю базу в память. То, что на нем можно написать неэффективный код - еще не означает что "для linq скорость не главное". Это посто означает что на linq можо написать неэффективный код, как и на всем остальном :)

Comment: В Linq используются делегаты, которые в отличие от C++ шаблонов не инлайнятся. Кстати для Max и Min для элементарных типов сделаны отдельные методы. Еще раз я изначально сказал, что  Fisher–Yates shuffle лучше, но есть и другие подходы. Пузырьковую сортировку никто не отменял.

Comment: @Serginio в linq используются синтаксические деревья, которые, в отличие от шаблонов C++, отображаются сразу в SQL. И, кстати, без упоминания вида @ username, без проблела, оповещения о комментариях не приходят.

Comment: @PashaPash Мы сейчас говорим о Linq to Object. Я знаю, что применяется. Я говорил об аналогах применения алгоритмов в БД. Да я тут недавно. Не знаю всех особенностей. Кстати по поводу линка и простых типов http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,dd1aa43ba83e50eb

Comment: @PashaPasha Узнал, что ключи кэширутся https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs#L2526

Comment: @Serginio: Это вы прочитали в исходниках одной конкретной реализации. Это ни в коем случае не является гарантией ни для данной имплементации на будущее или на прошлое, ни для других имплементаций. Гарантией может являться **только** документация. Пожалуйста, не пропагандируйте некорректные, и к тому же ещё и неэффективные решения.

Answer (score -1):

не хочешь использовать `Guid.NewGuid().ToString()` для случайной сортировки?
`var lstResult = yourList.OrderBy(x => Guid.NewGuid().ToString()).ToList();`

Comment: мы это обсуждали в другой теме, когда с точки зрения Стандарта вызывается лямбда, гарантируется ли единственный вызов для каждого элемента иначе сортировка будет совсем кривой.