# Почти рандомное заполнение двумерного массива C#

Tags: c#, массивы

Есть массив 5х5. Нужно заполнить его нулями, а два элемента, выбранные случайным образом, единицами

Comment: А в чем именно проблема? Что не получилось?

Comment: Можно взять два рандомных числа от 0 до 4,допустим 1 и 3, и потом в элемент массива с индексами 1 и 3 вставить единицу. Но будет ли так правильно,не мудрено ли?

Answer (score 2):

Вам по сути нужно выбрать два случайных индекса от 0 до 24.

Проще всего сделать это с использованием стандартного `Random`:

1. При помощи

   ```
   i1 = random.Next(25)
   ```

   получаете первый индекс.
2. Для второго индекса остаётся 24 значения, но выбирать надо среди всех значений, не равных `i1`. Для этого проще всего написать так:

   ```
   i2 = random.Next(24);
   if (i2 >= i1) i2++;
   ```

Окей, теперь вам нужно каждый из индексов превратить в двойной индекс от 0 до 4. Это делается при помощи

```
x = i / 5;
y = i % 5;
```

Дальше очевидно. Заполняете массив нулями, на двух подсчитанных позициях кладёте единицы.

Comment: а как еще пару элементов сделать рандомными?Использование i3 = random.Next(23)и i4= random.Next(22);; только ставит рядом новый рандомный элемент рядом с предыдущим рандомным

Comment: @РустемВалеев: Если нужно выборка из `k` рандомных элементов, проще, наверное, сделать выборку случайных элементов, как описано [здесь](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/547996/10105) (второй блок кода), только вести не до `n`, а до `k` (в вашем случае 4).

Answer (score 1):

Для определения 2 элементов нужно определить 4 индекса. Чтобы элементы были разные, все 4 индекса не должны быть равными, но могут быть равны 3 из них. Например, `[2,2,2,7]` имеет три двойки, но элементы разные - (2,2) и (2,7).

```
int[,] matrix = new int[5, 5];

List<int> indices = Enumerable.Range(0, 3)
    .Select(i => rnd.Next(0, 5))
    .ToList();

// Поиск 4го индекса.
List<int> used = new List<int>();
int i4;
do
{
    i4 = rnd.Next(0, 5);
} while (indices.Any(i => i == i4));
indices.Add(i4);

// Вставка единиц.
// Точнее, пример использования найденных индексов.
for (int i = 0; i < indices.Count / 2 + 1; i += 2)
{
    matrix[indices[i], indices[i + 1]] = 1;
}

// Проверка.
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
    {
        Console.Write(matrix[i, j] + " ");
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

1. Нулями заполнять элементы не нужно, т.к. это значение по умолчанию.
2. Чтобы псевдослучайные значения не повторялись, экземпляр `Random`
   долен быть `static`.