# Сортировка массива строк с числовыми значениями C#

Tags: c#, массивы, сортировка

Подскажите, как сортировать такой массив строк:

> "text‡11:35"
>   "other_text‡16:30"
>   "other_text1‡00:30"
>   ...
>   "more_other_text‡12:30"

Так, чтобы сами строки остались теми же строками (изменять нельзя) по возрастанию времени в конце строки, и строки с окончанием `00:**` ушли в конец также отсортированные по возрастанию в своей группе.
Пожалуйста, опишите словами, или примером на C#.

После проб и ошибок, нужный сорт получился с подсказки [A Petrov](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/184217/alexander-petrov) вот этот код отсортировал - как надо.

```
    private void SortLinksBySessTime()
    {
        string[] result = (from s in sessLinks
                      let dt = DateTime.Parse(s.Substring(s.Length - 5))
                      let dt2 = dt.Hour == 0 ? dt.AddDays(1) : dt
                      orderby dt2
                      select s)
         .ToArray();
    }
```

Comment: ваш вариант решения то где? или вы думаете вам на готово напишут решение задачи?

Comment: Честно говоря, надеялся :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так и не понял, с чем именно у вас проблема: с извлечением времени, с его парсингом или с такой сортировкой, чтобы время `00` было в конце?

Попробуйте так.

Синтаксис методов:

```
var result = list.Select(s =>
{
    var dt = DateTime.Parse(s.Substring(s.Length - 5));
    if (dt.Hour == 0)
        dt = dt.AddDays(1);
    return new { s, dt };
})
.OrderBy(a => a.dt)
.Select(a => a.s)
.ToList();
```

Синтаксис запросов (в данном случае проще и понятнее):

```
var result = (from s in list
              let dt = DateTime.Parse(s.Substring(s.Length - 5))
              let dt2 = dt.Hour == 0 ? dt.AddDays(1) : dt
              orderby dt2
              select s)
             .ToList();
```

Берём последние пять символов и парсим как время. Если час равен 0, то добавляем один день: в итоге это значение становится больше остальных и при сортировке по возрастанию окажется в конце.

Comment: Здравствуйте Александр Петров!
Большое спасибо за подсказку и решение!
Для меня это практика вуду пока, пока не разберусь.
Своё решение (подправленное ваше) выложу в топе, а вам ещё раз спасибо!

Comment: Просто комментарий... "Офтоп", как говорят члены долгих дискуссий в "чатах" и "ветках" комментариев статей, публикаций, вопросов и ответов.
_______________________________________

Answer (score 4):

Как-то так?:

```
var lines = new []{
    "text‡11:35",
    "other_text‡16:30",
    "other_text1‡00:30",
    "more_other_text‡12:30"
};

var sorted = (from line in lines
              let time = TimeSpan.Parse(line.Substring(line.IndexOf('‡') + 1))
              orderby time descending
              select line).ToList();
```

Comment: Как раз в дебри меня и завели типы.
Строка не распознана как действительный TimeSpan.
Почему-то не приводится ни к TimeSpan, ни к int

Comment: @YuriMorozov, при этом все строки в этом формате или есть и без чисел, например? Может, переводить в `TimeSpan` вручную?

Comment: Действительно, все строки имеют в конце 00:00, после специального разделителя (например text‡14:30). Пустых строк нет, null тоже нет.
Похоже, придётся просидеть над этим ещё сутки :)
Примеры выше не работают, так же, как и мои 50+ решений.

Comment: @YuriMorozov, попробуйте парсить TimeSpan вручную как-нибудь [так](http://pastebin.com/BugX9wB6), чтобы сразу увидеть, что же именно не парсится.

Answer (score 4):

Добавлю более оптимальный вариант

```
items.Select(i=> new {I=i, sort= ПарсингСтроки(I)}).OrderBy (i =>i.sort).Select(i=>i.I);
```

То есть сначала преобразум в класс с полем sort, отсортируем по этому полу, а затем получим первоначальные данные.
 Плюс в том, что данные будут парсится один раз.
 Можно проверить

Кстати это по мотивам [Как перемешать (случайно переставить) элементы в массиве?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/547996/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B-%D0%B2-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B5)

Comment: Вообще, OrderBy [кеширует ключи](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs#L2526) автоматически.

Comment: @Surfin Bird Спасибо! Буду знать.

Comment: Да, прикольно. Вот пример того, что нужно уметь прикидывать сложность алгоритмов в решении.