# Заполнение массива из диапазона на 5 больше или меньше от числа(Java)

Tags: java, алгоритм, math

Подскажите алгоритм который будет заполнять массив  случайными числами между которыми будет разница  на 5 больше или меньше от числа который уже находится в массиве, к примеру  массив должен быть таким :
`[26,1,6,20,11]`, где в массиве могут быть любые числа и в любом порядке, но с условием , что друг от друга они отделяются на 5 или меньше. Это как бы диапазон.

Числа могут быть в любом порядке, последовательности но значения этих чисел не должны быть +-5 от уже имеющегося числа в массиве.

Т.Е. так может быть : `[10,5,20,15]` или так: `[100,5,20]`.

А так уже Не может быть : `[9,5,11,3]` или так тоже не может : `[100,104,96]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Давайте рассмотрим геометрическую интерпретацию вашего задания.

Пусть наш диапазон допустимых чисел `[a, b]`, и нужно создать массив длины `n`. Тогда нам нужно бросить на отрезок `[a, b]` `n` различных чисел так, чтобы расстояние между ними было по крайней мере 5.

```
    [ a _ _ _ _ _ * _ _ _ _ _ _ * _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ b ]
                  |             |
                  |<--- >=5 --->|
```

Добавим к каждому из чисел «окрестность» диаметром 2. Тогда получится, что нам нужно вписать в отрезок `[a - 2, b + 2]` `n` таких вот *непересекающихся* окрестностей:

```
[ A _ _ _ _ _ * * * * * _ _ * * * * * _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ B ]
```

(`A = a - 2`, `B = b + 2`). При этом начала окрестностей тоже должны иметь целые координаты.

Схлопнем каждую из окрестностей в точку, при этом длина всего отрезка уменьшится на `4 * n`.

Теперь наша картинка упростилась: на отрезок длины `(b + 2) - (a - 2) + 1 - 4 * n` нужно бросить `n` различных точек. А это известная задача. Она решается при помощи классической [случайной выборки с резервуаром](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reservoir_sampling), [вот тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/547997/10105) есть код на C#. Модифицируем его для наших нужд:

```
int[] Generate(int a, int b, int n) {
    int max = (b + 2) - (a - 2) + 1 - 4 * n;
    if (n > max)
        throw new Exception("Задача неразрешима");
    int[] result = ReservoirSampling(n, max);

    // выборка неотсортирована, сортируем
    Arrays.sort(result);

    // и возвращаем нужные индексы:
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        result[i] += a + (4 * i);

    return result;
}

int[] ReservoirSampling(int n, int max) {
    Random r = new Random(); // этот экземпляр нужно сделать глобальным
    int[] result = new int[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        result[i] = i;

    for (int i = n; i < max; i++) {
        int j = r.nextInt(i + 1);
        if (j < n)
            result[j] = i;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Проверка: http://ideone.com/yCLwqg

Answer (score 0):

Возможно я не совсем понял вопрос, но что мешает выбрать произвольное число, заполнить массив числами каждый раз увеличивая предыдущее число на n, а затем перемешать элементы массива?

Код будет выглядеть так:

```
int number = 5;
int count = 10;
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>(count);
list.add(ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(100));
for (int i = 1; i < count; i++)
    list.add(list.get(i - 1) + number);

Collections.shuffle(list);
System.out.println(list);
```

Вывод

> [111, 106, 116, 91, 121, 81, 96, 76, 101, 86]

Comment: Если просто увеличивать каждый раз, можно вылезти за верхнюю границу.

Comment: Что то не вижу в вопросе упоминания про верхнюю границу, если же речь идеть про overflow то ничто не запрещает брать рандомное число с оглядкой на Integer.MAX_VALUE

Comment: Окей, согласен. Но тогда другая проблема: ваш алгоритм не выдаёт все возможные решения. Например, он никогда не выдаст `[1, 7, 512]`. Это по идее не очень хорошо, результат выходит неслучайный.