# Нужно по индексу элемента списка достать его число

Tags: c#

Нужно по индексу элемента списка достать его число и присвоить значению NewCard ,но оно жалуеся на то что элементы списка являются enum

```
public class Deck
{
    public int NewCard { get; set; }
    public static List<Card>Cards = new List<Card>();

    public static Random rnd = new Random();

    static int GetEnumValueAsInt(CardNumber NewCard)
    {
        return (int)NewCard;
    }
    public void Take()
    {
        foreach (Suit suitName in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Suit)))
        {
            foreach (CardNumber cardNumber in Enum.GetValues(typeof(CardNumber)))
            {
                Cards.Add(new Card()
                {
                    Suits = suitName,
                    CardNumbers = cardNumber
                });
            }
        }
        var rand = rnd.Next(Cards.Count);
        NewCard = rand;
    }
}
public enum CardNumber
{
    Ace = 11,
    King = 10,
    Queen = 10,
    Jack = 10,
    Ten = 10,
    Nine = 9,
    Eight = 8,
    Seven = 7,
    Six = 6,
    Five = 5,
    Four = 4,
    Three = 3,
    Two = 2
}
```

если делать так

```
NewCard=Cards[rand];
```

выдает ошибку

Comment: @AK так ,а что можно с этим сделать

Comment: так и не понимаю зачем вы каждый раз генерите колоду при попытке достать карту

Comment: ну вы тут получили номер карты по порядку генерации, а что хотите получить?

Comment: @AK для начала я хочу просто вытащить карту и ее стоимость(которая указана в enum) добавить к счету пользователя ,после этого я хочу удалить эту карту чтоб дальше ее нельзя было повторно выбрать ,но как сделать это я знаю ,проблема в том то я не могу достать из карты её число

Comment: что такое "число карты"? ее значение в enum?

Comment: @yolosora да ,для того чтоб прибавить к счету пользователя

Comment: ну так зачем вам вообще свойство newcard, делайте возвращаемое значение типа int и кидайте его через `return`. для того что бы удалять карту вам тем более не надо каждый раз генерить колоду, генерьте ее в конструкторе.

Comment: Вообще у вас налицо ощутимое непонимание базовых концепций программирования на шарпе, уделите хотя бы пару вечеров на то чтобы пробежаться по базовому мануалу на msdn, будет уже проще.

Comment: @yolosora А также не хватает навыков описания предметной области. Есть неозвученный термин - "набор карт" (полная колода из 52 карт, набор из 36 карт и т.п.), нет класса CardSet под него. Неясны зоны ответственности класса Колода (Deck), а уж "счёт пользователя" и прочее - вообще где-то за горизонтом.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ответ на вопрос "как перемешать массив карт" [укладывается в однострочник](https://stackoverflow.com/q/108819/5752652)

```
cards.OrderBy(x => rnd.Next()).ToArray()
```

Полный пример со всеми классами, которые пришлось собрать из вопросов топикстартертера:

```
void Main()
{
    var cardSetShort = CardSetHelper.Full52();
    var cardSetShuffled = CardSetHelper.Shuffle(cardSetShort.Cards, new Random());
    //cardSetShuffled.Dump();
}

// Define other methods and classes here

public static class CardSetHelper
{
    // Влом описывать руками наборы карт
    public static CardSet Full52()
    {
        var cardSet = new List<Card>();
        foreach(Suit suit in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Suit)))
        {
            foreach (CardValue value in Enum.GetValues(typeof(CardValue)))
            {
                cardSet.Add(new Card(suit, value));
            }
        }
        return new CardSet("Полная колода из 52 карт", cardSet.ToArray());
    }

    // Собственно тасуем карты
    public static Card[] Shuffle(Card[] cards, Random rnd)
    {
        return cards.OrderBy(x => rnd.Next()).ToArray();
    }
}

public class CardSet
{
    public CardSet(string title, Card[] cards)
    {
        this.Title = title;
        this.Cards = cards;
    }

    public string Title { get; private set; }

    public Card[] Cards { get; private set; }
}

public class Card
{
    public Card(Suit suit, CardValue value)
    {
        this.Suit = suit;
        this.Value = value;
    }

    public Suit Suit { get; private set; }

    public CardValue Value { get; private set; }
}

public enum Suit
{
    Spades = 1,
    Hearts = 2,
    Diamonds = 3,
    Clubs = 4
};

public enum CardValue
{
    Ace = 11,
    King = 10,
    Queen = 10,
    Jack = 10,
    Ten = 10,
    Nine = 9,
    Eight = 8,
    Seven = 7,
    Six = 6,
    Five = 5,
    Four = 4,
    Three = 3,
    Two = 2,
};
```

Реализованный метод "Тасовать колоду" предполагает перемешивание всего набора карт.

В качестве бесплатного подарка - метод генерации полной колоды из 52 карт, описание колоды из 36 карт - думайте сами.

И вот где-то после этих всех манипуляций у вас на горизонте замаячит класс Deck ("Колода"), в котором будет метод Take ("Тянуть N карт сверху") и другая игровая логика. Скажем, вернуть под низ колоды или что там ещё по игре предусмотрено.

---

Update [@VladD обратил](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/43316126#43316126) моё внимание на неоптимальность перемешивания:

> OrderBy(x => rnd.Next())
>
> Это плохо по многим причинам.
>
> Во-первых, нет гарантии, что OrderBy кеширует ключи А чем может
>   обернуться сортировка по внезапно меняющемуся ключу, понятно.
>
> Во-вторых, это лишняя сложность O(n log n), хотя можно за O(n)

Попробуйте воспользоваться его советам и переписать этот метод используя алгоритм Fisher–Yates shuffle:

- [Как перемешать (случайно переставить) элементы в массиве?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/547996/213987)
- [Is using Random and OrderBy a good shuffle algorithm?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1287567/5752652)

Comment: спасибо ,на вашем примере постараюсь разобраться что к чему