# Генерация случайных дробных чисел

Tags: c#, алгоритм

Есть вот такая задача: Сгенерировать массив чисел, сумма которых составит 1. Кол-во чисел вводится с клавиатуры. Решение может быть любое главное получить итоговую сумму 1 (Не желательно большое кол-во нулей)

Comment: Числа могут быть любые (положительные/отрицательные)? Или только из интервала [0;1]?

Comment: Какое должно быть распределение у полученных чисел?

Comment: ТС, если вам требуется равномерное распределение, рекомендую рассмотреть ответ @AnT: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/820415/218063

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Генерируем N **любых** неотрицательных чисел.
Вычисляем их сумму.
Делим каждое на эту сумму.

Пример реализации:

```
int count = 10;
Random random = new Random();
int[] integers = new int[count];
long sum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
{
    integers[i] = random.Next();
    sum += integers[i];
}
double[] doubles = new double[count];
for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
    doubles[i] = (double)integers[i] / sum;
Console.WriteLine(string.Join("\n", doubles));
Console.WriteLine(doubles.Sum());
```

[`random.Next()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/9b3ta19y(v=vs.110).aspx) возвращает неотрицательное случайное целое число.
Для накопления суммы берем `long`-переменную во избежание переполнений.

Comment: Кстати а вот эта идея уже куда интереснее:) кстати на бумаге хорошо решаемая:)

Comment: @JMNext, этим же способом выполняется нормализация векторов до единичных

Comment: :) Блиииин как все просто оказалось... А я выдумываю сложные алгоритмы елки палки))

Comment: Такой подход даст "кособокое" распределение результата. То есть он лучше, чем "много нулей", но на самом деле страдает от той же проблемы, только менее явно.

Comment: @AnT, обоснуйте.

Comment: Если бы вы делили полученные значения на предзаданную *константу*, то равномерность распределения бы сохранялась, но так как вы делите на сумму *самих случайных значений*, равномерность теряется. Сумма нескольких случайных величин распределена не *равномерно*, а *нормально*. Например, гистограмма суммы `N` бросаний игральной кости имеет хорошо нам знакомую форму колокола. Вот именно на такую неравномерно распределенную случайную величину вы и выполняете деление в вашем варианте . И именно из-за этого теряете равномерность распределения результата.

Comment: Проведите натурный (или даже мысленный) эксперимент с вашим решением для N=2, то есть разбиение единицы на 2 случайных слагаемых. И вы сразу увидите, что ваши разбиения будут намного более густо сконцентрированы вокруг значения 0.5. Вот как выглядит распределение, порождаемое вашим подходом, для деления на два слагаемых: https://imgur.com/a/A7ClmkH

Comment: @AnT, ага, спасибо, мысль ясна. Но пока не понятно, как себя ведёт распределение при увеличении количества чисел.

Comment: Поведение суммы случайных значений вполне изучено (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irwin%E2%80%93Hall_distribution). Именно "тяготение" суммы к середине диапазона (т.е. того, на что вы делите) и приводит к неравномерности распределения результата.

Answer (score 14):

Вариант с делением на сумму заранее сгенерированных чисел не дает равномерного распределения результата из-за того, что сумма равномерно распределенных величин сама не является равномерно распределенной. А равномерность распределения результата в таких задачах обычно подразумевается.

Более подходящим с точки зрения распределения решением будет следующее: сгенерировать `N-1` неубывающих равномерно распределенных случайных чисел в диапазоне `[0, 1]`

r<sub>1</sub> ≤ r<sub>2</sub> ≤ r<sub>3</sub> ≤ ... ≤ r<sub>N-1</sub>

затем положить r<sub>0</sub> = 0 и r<sub>N</sub> = 1 и в качестве искомых чисел взять попарные разности в соседях

r<sub>1</sub> - r<sub>0</sub>, r<sub>2</sub> - r<sub>1</sub>, r<sub>3</sub> - r<sub>2</sub>, ..., r<sub>N</sub> - r<sub>N-1</sub>

На C++

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  unsigned N = 10;
  std::vector<unsigned> r(N + 1);

  r.front() = 0;
  std::generate(r.begin() + 1, r.end() - 1, std::rand);
  std::sort(r.begin() + 1, r.end() - 1);
  r.back() = RAND_MAX;

  for (unsigned i = 1; i <= N; ++i)
    std::cout << double(r[i] - r[i - 1]) / RAND_MAX << " ";

  std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Похоже что это и есть единственный верный ответ в плане равномерности распределения

Comment: @Zergatul, а что вы имеете ввиду под равномерностью? Я вот сгенерировал тремя способами миллион раз пакет из 10 чисел и получил такую картинку: [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xN2Fo.png), [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SXIDc.png). А вот здесь пакеты по 100 чисел: [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jRgPe.png). Как видно, мой алгоритм дает примерно равное количество чисел на начальном интервале (от 0 до 0,15). Алгоритм yolosora дает очень много мелких чисел. Алгоритм AnT дает тем меньше чисел, чем они больше, но не так много мелких как предыдущий.

Comment: @АндрейNOP Смотрите, возьмем самый простой вариант задачи, сгенерить 2 числа, чья сумма = 1. Какой самый интуитивно верный ответ? Взять и разрезать интервал [0, 1) в случайном месте. Что и делает AnT. Ваш алгоритм будет генерировать числа ближе к 0.5 чаще. А теперь что не так с yolosora. Его алгоритм не зависит от количества чисел. Возьмем 10 чисел. По его алгоритму получается, что вероятность появления числа 0.9 на первой итерации равна 0.1. Возьмем 1000 чисел. Снова та же самая вероятность появления 0.9.

Comment: В общем это зависит от потребности ТС, если он генерирует 10 чисел и хочет чтобы они были близки к 0.1, то мой алгоритм ему больше пойдет. Правда, в идеале тогда ему нужен алгоритм default locale :D

Comment: @АндрейNOP: Вы забыли объяснить, что же именно изображено на этих ваших картинках. Это графики? Графики чего именно?

Comment: По оси ординат количество чисел, попавших в данный интервал, всего 1000 интервалов

Comment: "сумма равномерно распределенных величин сама не является равномерно распределенной" - а можно какое-нибудь подтверждение этому утверждению? Я вот с ходу нашел только утверждение про сумму равномерно распределенных величин, определенных на различных интервалах.

Comment: @VTT: Я уже давал ссылку: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irwin%E2%80%93Hall_distribution. Сумма равномерно распределенных - это распределение Ирвина-Холла, очень похожее на нормальное. На равномерное вообще не похоже.

Comment: @VTT: Да это должно быть  и интуитивно понятно. Экстремальные значения суммы получаются только единственными комбинациями слагаемых. Неэкстремальные значения суммы можно получить множеством разных комбинаций слагаемых. Центр диапазона суммы получается максимальным количеством разнообразных комбинаций. Именно поэтому распределение суммы не равномерно, а имеет форму типичного колокола. Возьмите, к примеру, сумму двух случайных битов (двух вызовов `rand() % 2`). Очевидно, что сумма `1` будет получаться *намного* чаще, чем сумма `0` или сумма `2`.

Answer (score 10):

`rnd` - `Random`

```
 static double[] Generate(int count)
 { 
    var result = new double[count];
    var max = 1.0;
    for (int i = 0; i < count - 1; i++)
    {
       result[i] = rnd.NextDouble() * max;
       max -= result[i];
    }
    result[count-1] = max;
    return result;
 }
```

Дополнительно массив можно перемешать если критично то, что  при такой генерации в среднем следующее значение становится меньше предыдущего. Пример простого перемешивания:

`result.OrderBy(x => rnd.Next()).ToArray();`

Comment: Последнее число будет глубоко отрицательное и сильно отличаться от остальных. Не понятно только на сколько это критично для автора.

Comment: @АндрейNOP почему будет отрицательное? Тут скорее другая проблема, числа с каждой итераций в среднем будут становиться меньше.

Comment: @АндрейNOP если первое будет 0.7, то второе не будет больше, чем 0.3

Comment: Ах, нет, всё правильно. Вы же на max каждый раз умножаете. Понял ваш алгоритм. Но да, хоть числа и не будут отрицательные, но будут все равно не равномерно распределены - дальние числа будут меньше

Comment: @АндрейNOP ну в принципе после этого массив можно перемешать :D

Comment: Согласен, поставил +. Алгоритм имеет право на существование, хоть и будет иметь большую сложность, чем мой.

Comment: Всё хорошо, но способ перемешивания ужасен. Посмотрите обсуждение [этого ответа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/548310/10105).

Comment: @VladD круто и просто, спасибо за ликбез! Подправлю ответ

Comment: Ваш алгоритм дает очень большое число мелких чисел, например, если сгенерировать миллион раз пакет по 10 чисел, то из всех 10 млн. треть будет меньше 0,001! Два соседних алгоритма будут иметь не более 100 тыс. таких чисел: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/820241/Генерация-случайных-дробных-чисел/820259#comment1329334_820415

Answer (score 6):

Ну, раз ограничений никаких нет, то самое примитивное решение: массив в котором первый элемент равен 1, а остальные — 0.

```
int n = 5;
var arr = new decimal[n];
arr[0] = 1;
```

**ОБНОВЛЕНИЕ:** Добавлено уточнение, что много нулей нежелательно. Из-за этого решение не подходит.

Вариант №2: Заполняем массив значениями 1/n:

```
int n = 6;
var value = 1.0m/n;
var arr = Enumerable.Repeat(value, n).ToArray();
```

Тут возникает проблема: из-за ошибок округления при делении, сумма может не сойтись. Для того, чтобы сумма сошлась компенсируем первый элемент:

```
arr[0] = 1-(value*(n-1));
```

Comment: Если решение покажется недостаточно случайным, то можно модифицировать алгоритм и сделать 1 не первый элемент, а рандомный. :)

Comment: много нулей как то не очень смотриться. И да ща исправлю. Надо рационально как то сгенерить:)

Comment: @JMNext Да, пожалуй, надо уточнить условие. А то в заголовке про случайные дробные числа, а в тексте они не упоминаются.

Comment: @Yaant Ну это уже будет полный хаос и неразбериха.

Comment: Эх, не хотел бы я быть вашим заказчиком ;)

Answer (score 3):

Одна из идей - создавать большие целые числа, а затем делить их, к примеру, на 1000. Так у Вас сформируется массив дробных чисел =) Действия выполняемых, пока сумма всех элементов не станет равной 1. Каждое сформированное число нужно проверить: подходит ли оно условию (должно быть меньше разности 1 и сумма остальных элементов массива).

Comment: и он будет равен 1?

Comment: великолепное решение, осталось ответить на поставленный вопрос, который заключается в другом

Comment: А что, идея хорошая - нагенерировать любых чисел и разделить каждое на сумму всех! Просто автор неудачно сформулировал ответ...

Comment: Нет, прочитайте что вам Андрей написал, то что вы предлагаете опять не подходит, по критерию "нам надо указать число таких чисел"

Comment: О нет, автор изменил ответ и его уже понесло не туда... Прочитайте мой предыдущий комментарий.

Comment: @АндрейNOP уже понял, поэтому удалил свой комментарий :)