# Расположить на отрезке N точек чтобы между любыми соседними точками было достаточно места?

Tags: javascript, алгоритм, случайные-числа

Сейчас объясню, что я имею ввиду.

Пробую отрисовать на canvas свисающие на нитках снежинки. Фактически, зная ширину canvas и заданное число N точек я просто генерирую N случайных чисел в диапазоне от 0 до canvas.width

```
getRandomInt(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
}
```

И нажимая F5 вижу, что в некоторых случаях сгенерированные числа находятся слишком близко друг к другу:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Просто само изображение снежинки, которое будет находиться в конце вертикальной линии гораздо больше чем изображенное расстояние (раза в три точно), будет налезать друг на друга:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Поэтому мне нужен какой-то более подходящий алгоритм генерации, который генерирует для заданных N, max и distance готовый набор чисел, так чтобы между любой парой из эти N чисел (от 0 до max каждое) расстояние было не меньше distance.

Понимаю, что не при всех вариантах чисел это будет возможно. Например, если надо на отрезок длиной 100 кинуть две точки, то нельзя гарантировать расстояние между ними в 101.

Принимаются как идеи алгоритма, так и (предпочтительнее) готовая функция.

Comment: Генерируйте числа в диапазоне от 0 до max/distance, округляйте до единиц и умножайте на distance

Comment: А еще можно обыграть этот момент, если подвесить снежинки на разной высоте, чтобы они не налезали друг на друга

Comment: можно генерировать точки на плоскости и смотреть чтобы они были не ближе радиуса снежинки :)

Comment: Разбить `max` на N равных отрезков, внутри отрезка генерить точку таким образом, чтобы она была не ближе `distance/2` к любой из двух границ своего отрезка

Comment: Еще нужно? Реализовал на java.

Answer (score 5):

По-моему, проще идти, так сказать, в обратную сторону:

`N` точек потребуют `distance * N` места. Соответственно, остается `free = max - distance * N` свободного места, которое надо дополнительно распределить в промежутках между точками. Генерируем `N` чисел на отрезке `[0, free]`, разбивая таким образом этот отрезок на `N + 1` частей, добавляем эти части между точками, а также до и после.

Замечание: предполагается, что расстояние от крайних точек до концов отрезка тоже должно быть не меньше `distance`. Модификация алгоритма для иного случая предлагается в качестве упражнения. :)

Comment: Отличное решение, чем-то похоже на идею здесь: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/820415/218063

Answer (score 2):

Хм. Задача одномерная.

Шаг 1. Как в вопросе, получили положение первой точки. Из отрезка `canvas.width` вырезаем кусок шириной две снежинки и центром в первой точке.

...

Шаг i. Сложив длины оставшихся отрезков, получаем случайное число внутри этой суммы. Идя по отрезкам, находим тот, в который попадает эта новая точка. Вырезаем вокруг нее кусок шириной две снежинки.

Comment: А вы не хотите принять участие в [Новогоднем конкурсе 2020](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1062989/28748)? Почитайте этот пост, совсем необязательно делать анимашку `frontend`