# Выбрать из списка 400 случайных элементов

Tags: c#, list, случайные-числа

Есть список:

```
List<string> list = new List<string>();
```

Его count 10 000. Нужно выбрать 400 случайных (рандомных) элементов этого списка и поместить их в новый список:

```
List<string> listNew = new List<string>();
```

Если использовать r.Next(0, list.Count - 1), то есть вероятность того, что рандом может выбрать один и тот же элемент дважды. Как этого избежать и выбрать 400 рандмных уникальных элементов?

Comment: 400 из 10 000 - не так уж много, просто запоминайте индексы уже выбранных элементов в Hashset и при выборе следующего проверяйте чтобы его не было в Hashset

Comment: Заводите hashset и складываете а него рандомы, пока он не станет содержать 400 элементов. Второй вариант — заводите список на 10000 элементов, выбираете в нем случайный элемент и удаляем его, выбираем следующий случайный и тоже удаляем, и так 400 раз. В вашем случае скорее всего первый вариант лучше

Comment: Удалил старую чушь, сделайте как было предложено, лучше случайно генерировать позицию и проверять, не выбрана ли она ранее через тот же HashSet, если производительность не критична.

Comment: Связанный вопрос: [Как перемешать (случайно переставить) элементы в массиве?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/547997/218063)

Answer (score 4):

На первый взгляд, это классическая задача на алгоритм [Reservoir Sampling](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reservoir_sampling). Задача решается за один последовательный проход по списку, и при этом для достижения равновероятной выборки вам даже не надо заранее знать количества элементов в списке. При этом не нужно прибегать к ужасной порочной практике "проб и ошибок" (проверка "уже брали - еще не брали"), которую часто предлагают использовать при составлении наивных алгоритмов для решения данной задачи.

Алгоритм таков:

1. Заводим массив из 400 элементов и заполняем его первыми 400 элементами списка.
2. Читаем в цикле дальнейшие элементы списка (с 401-го и далее):

   2.1. Берем i-тый элемент из списка и с вероятностью `400/i` принимаем решение сохранить этот элемент в нашей выборке. Если принято решение "не сохранять", то просто пропускаем его.

   2.2. Если принято решение сохранить элемент, сохраняем его в случайную позицию в нашем массиве (выбросив оттуда предыдущий элемент).

Пройдя таким циклом весь список до конца, мы получим 400 равновероятно выбранных элементов списка.

Как видите, для эффективной реализации выбранные 400 элементов желательно в процессе работы алгоритма хранить в массиве, а не в списке. Тут уже думайте сами, как лучше поступить: завести изначально массив, а затем скопировать выбранные элементы в список, или сразу хранить их в списке, пожертвовав эффективностью прямого доступа при замене на шаге 2.2.

---

Однако если ваш исходный список предоставляет возможность эффективного прямого доступа (см. комментарий @Андрей NOP), то вариант "проб и ошибок" будет вполне жизнеспособным и даже более эффективным, так как 400 намного меньше 10000.

Comment: Коллекция `List<>` в .Net это тот же массив с константным доступом по индексу (просто со спрятанным от пользователя изменением вместимости). Я это про "желательно ... хранить в массиве, а не в списке", уход от List<> к массиву ничего ровным счетом не даст

Comment: Пример на C#: https://ideone.com/HlfyON Хорошо было бы показать в ответе вывод вероятности для i-го элемента. Понимаю, что это можно найти по ссылкам, но здесь было бы нагляднее.

Answer (score 3):

**Если производительность некритична перемешиваем весь список**

Неоптимальный и грубый, но достаточно прямолинейный подход: перемешать весь список в случайном порядке и выбрать первые 400:

```
var random = new Random();
var listNew = list.OrderBy(s=> random.Next()).Take(400).ToList();
```

Неоптимальный т.к. будет сортировать весь список.
Грубый т.к. коллизии случайных чисел приведут к тому, что попадание первых по порядку элементов будет на какую долю выше.

**Поход для малой выборки: отбираем уникальные индексы**

Напишем метод, который генерирует бесконечную последовательность случайных индексов:

```
private static Random random;

public static IEnumerable<int> RandomNumbers(int maxValue)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            yield return random.Next(maxValue);
        }
    }
```

С помощью метода получим 400 уникальных индексов и отберем элементы:

```
var uniqueIndices = RandomNumbers(list.Count).Distinct().Take(400);
var listNew = uniqueIndices.Select(i => list[i]).ToList();
```

Недостаток этого подхода в то что он подходит только для выбора малого (по сравнению с размером исходной выборки) количества элементов. Если Вам потребуется отобрать 9999 элементов, этот метод будет неоптимален ввиду частых совпадений случайных чисел.

Comment: Следует заметить, что чем большее число элементов мы выбираем из входного списка, тем дольше будет выбираться каждый следующий элемент из-за частого совпадения сгенерированных индексов с уже использованными. В этом плане алгоритм из [соседнего ответа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/841845/218063) гораздо более оптимален.

Comment: @АндрейNOP Точно, спасибо! Уточню в ответе.

Comment: @defaultlocale А в случае 9999 элементов из 10000 не проще случайно выбрать ненужный индекс?

Comment: @John Проще, но это дополнительная логика. 9999 — крайний пример, коллизии начнут оказывать влияние и на меньших выборках. В любом случае Ant уже показал универсальный O(n) алгоритм.