# заполнение трехмерного массива с помощью Random

Tags: c#, .net

Можно ли заполнить трехмерный массив с помощью Random так, чтобы элементы не повторялись?

Comment: можно (+ 7 символов)

Answer (score 4):

Итак, напишем метод-расширение для ленивого перемешивания, основанный на [ответе @VladD](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/547997/248572):

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Shuffle<T>(this IEnumerable<T> Source)
{
    T[] data = Source.ToArray();
    for (int i = data.Length - 1; i > -1; --i)
    {
        // Rand - глобальная переменная типа System.Random
        int newIndex = Rand.Next(i + 1);
        yield return data[newIndex];
        data[newIndex] = data[i];
    }
}
```

Тогда заполнение массива можно описать так:

```
int[,,] arr = new int[5, 5, 5];

// Сгенерируем последовательность чисел по длине массива,
// перемешаем и получим ее энумератор
IEnumerator<int> randoms = Enumerable.Range(0, arr.Length).Shuffle().GetEnumerator();
randoms.MoveNext();

// Запустим цикл для каждого измерения массива
for (int i = 0; i < arr.GetLength(0); ++i)
    for (int j = 0; j < arr.GetLength(1); ++j)
        // В самом глубоком цикле будем также двигать и энумератор
        for (int k = 0; k < arr.GetLength(2); ++k, randoms.MoveNext())
            // Присваиваем текущей ячейке текущее значение энумератора
            arr[i, j, k] = randoms.Current;
```

Логика такова:

1. Генерируем последовательность чисел по общей длине массива
2. Перемешиваем ее случайным образом
3. Получаем случайную последовательность чисел, не проводя никаких
   проверок на уникальность каждого нового числа (так как изначально каждое число уже уникально))

---

Чем этот вариант лучше варианта с генерацией (псевдо)случайного числа и последующей проверкой на то, было ли оно использовано ранее?

Представьте, что [ГПСЧ](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80_%D0%BF%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85_%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BB) **5000 раз** выдал нам одно и то же число (или даже проще - выдал числа, которые уже использовались ранее). Да, на практике Вы сие вряд ли встретите, так что ситуация чисто гипотетическая. Но на примере этого гипертрофированного исхода я показываю, что сложность метода трудно предсказать и порой она может превысить ожидаемые пределы

---

В качестве бонуса - заполнение массива любой размерности и любой длины:

```
// Надо бы обозначить Arr как ref-параметр (пусть он итак ссылочный),
// дабы можно было ожидать его изменения
// Однако тогда его нельзя использовать в лямбдах
// Так что положимся на самодокументируемость названия)
public static void FillWithRandoms(Array Arr)
{
    // Метод предназначен только для массивов чисел
    if (Arr.GetType().GetElementType() != typeof(int))
        throw new TypeAccessException("This method available only for int arrays!");

    // Закэшируем длины всех измерений массива
    int[] lengths = Enumerable.Range(0, Arr.Rank).Select(x => Arr.GetLength(x)).ToArray();

    // Создадим массив индексов по числу измерений
    int[] indices = new int[Arr.Rank];

    // Это место Вам уже знакомо)
    IEnumerator<int> randoms = Enumerable.Range(0, Arr.Length).Shuffle().GetEnumerator();
    randoms.MoveNext();

    // Цикл по всей длине массива
    // Каждую итерацию двигаем как энумератор randoms, так и значения в indices
    for (int i = 0; i < Arr.Length; ++i, randoms.MoveNext(), MoveNext(Arr.Rank - 1))
        Arr.SetValue(randoms.Current, indices);

    // Рекурсивная функция (храни Боже локальные функции, как мы без них жили-то...),
    // которая изменяет массив indices, постепенно перебирая индексы всех элементов массива:
    // 0, 0, 0, ..., 0
    // 0, 0, 0, ..., 1
    // 0, 0, 0, ..., 2
    // ...
    // 3, 2, 4, ..., 0
    // ...
    void MoveNext(int index)
    {
        if (index != -1 && ++indices[index] == lengths[index])
        {
            indices[index] = 0;
            MoveNext(index - 1);
        }
    }
}
```

Тогда заполнение Вашего массива сведется к:

```
int[,,] arr = new int[1, 2, 3];
FillWithRandoms(arr);
```

Вот и вся задача ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

---

Надеюсь, мой ответ помог Вам!
Желаю удачи в дальнейших свершениях!

Comment: Хороший вариант. Вопрос переставал быть томным :)

Comment: @trydex: благодарю) Просто сам недавно в своем расширении писал перестановочку, да и **VladD** про нее вспомнил, так что просто грех был не написать)

Answer (score 1):

Размерность массива не играет никакой роли. Вам нужно сверяться со значениями, которые уже находятся в массиве или сохранять сгенерированные элементы куда-либо, например в `Hashset<T>`, и проверять при последуещей генерации был ли элемент получен ранее.

Метод генерации будет выглядеть примерно так:

```
static HashSet<int> numbers = new HashSet<int>();
static Random r = new Random();

public static int GenerateUniqueNumber()
{
    while (true)
    {
        var n = r.Next(0, 1000);
        if (!numbers.Contains(n))
        {
            numbers.Add(n);
            return n;
        }
    }
}
```

Само заполнение массива будет выглядеть так:

```
var arr = new int[5,5,5];

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
    {
        for (int k = 0; k < 5; k++)
        {
            arr[i, j, k] = GenerateUniqueNumber();
        }
    }
}
```

---

Вариант от @tym32167 с первоначальным заполнением списка случайными значениями и последующим получением с удалением этих значений:

```
    var numbers = Enumerable.Range(0, 10000).ToList();
    var arr = new int[5, 5, 5];

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
        {
            for (int k = 0; k < 5; k++)
            {
                var randomIndex = r.Next(0, numbers.Count);
                var number = numbers[randomIndex];
                numbers.RemoveAt(randomIndex);

                arr[i, j, k] = number;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: было бы неплохо ещё упомянуть второй вариант с со списком возможных случайных значений

Comment: @tym32167, Не совсем понял, что вы имеете ввиду. Разверните мысль)

Comment: ну вот смотрите - в вашей текущей реализации, если выбирать 10000 случайных значений из диапазона 0-9999, то для последнего значения у вас будет 99999 элементов в хештаблице, то есть при равномерном распределении вам понадобится 10к итераций чтобы найти последний варант случайной величины

Comment: или вы можете создать список со всеми возможными значниями (0-9999), и при генерации выбирать случайный элемет из списка и удалять его

Comment: @tym32167, Теперь понял)

Comment: @tym32167: немного алгоритмики по теме: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/547996/10105

Comment: @VladD: согласен. Чем постоянно дергать лист, который будет периодически менять свою размерность, будет лучше получить лениво перемешанную последовательность изначально упорядоченных чисел)

Comment: @VladD хороший вариант, если диапазон и размерность массива совпадают :)