# Создать массив из полученных значений и присвоить элементу значение нового массива Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

Есть два типа объектов:

- кнопка (не UI элемент, а спрайт с коллайдером, и компонентом AudioSourse);
- карта (тоже спрайт с коллайдером).

Суть задачи: из набора карт (ну пусть будет штук 8) на экране появляется три рандомных. При нажатии кнопки должен воспроизвестись звук соответствующий одной из появившихся карт.
Скрипт карты:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class MemoryCard : MonoBehaviour {
    [SerializeField] private SceneController controller;
    private int _id;
    public int id
    {
        get { return _id; } //Добавление функции чтения
    }

    public void SetCard(int id, Sprite image) // Открытый метод, которым могут пользоваться другие сценарии для передачи указанному объекту новых спрайтов.
    {
        _id = id;
        GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = image;
           }
    private void OnMouseDown()
    {
                Debug.Log("id карточки" + _id);
    }
}
```

Скрипт кнопки:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class ButtonScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private SceneController controller;
    private int _id;
    public int id
    {
        get { return _id; } //Добавление функции чтения
    }
    private AudioSource Voice;

    public void SetButton(int idV, AudioClip Clip) // Открытый метод, которым могут пользоваться другие сценарии для передачи указанному объекту новых спрайтов.
    {
        _id = id;
      GetComponent<AudioSource>().clip = Clip;
    }

    private void OnMouseDown()
    {
        Voice = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
        Voice.Play();
        Debug.Log("id кнопки" + _id);
    }
}
```

Скрипт Контроллера сцены:

```
    using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using UnityEngine;
    using UnityEngine.UI;

    public class SceneController : MonoBehaviour {

            [SerializeField] private MemoryCard originalCard;
        [SerializeField] private ButtonScript originalButton;
        [SerializeField] private Sprite[] images;
        [SerializeField] private AudioClip[] Clips;

        public const int gridRows = 1; // количество рядов
        public const int gridCols = 3; // количество карт в ряду
        public const float offsetX = 4f; // расстояние между картами
        public const float offsetY = 4f;

        // Use this for initialization
        void Start()
        {
Vector3 startPos = originalCard.transform.position; // положение первой карты
 int[] numbers = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 }; // массив для индетификаторов спрайтов, НАДО ПЕРЕДЕЛАТЬ В ЦИКЛ

            numbers = ShuffleArray(numbers); // вызов функции перемешивания
                                             // numbersVoices = ShuffleArrayVoices(numbersVoices);

            for (int i = 0; i < gridCols; i++) // столбцы и строки
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < gridRows; j++)
                {
                    MemoryCard card;
                   if (i == 0 && j == 0)
                    {
                        card = originalCard;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        card = Instantiate(originalCard) as MemoryCard;
                    }

                    int index = j * gridCols + i;
                    int id = numbers[index]; // Получаем идентификаторы из перемешанного списка, а не из случайных чисел.
                    card.SetCard(id, images[id]);

                    float posX = (offsetX * i) + startPos.x;
                    float posY = -(offsetY * j) + startPos.y;
                    card.transform.position = new Vector3(posX, posY, startPos.z);
                }
            }
        }

 // алгоритм перемешивания Кнута
        private int[] ShuffleArray(int[] numbers)
            {
            int[] newArray = numbers.Clone() as int[];
            for (int i = 0; i < newArray.Length; i++)
            {
                int tmp = newArray[i];
                int r = Random.Range(i, newArray.Length);
                newArray[i] = newArray[r];
                newArray[r] = tmp;
            }
            return newArray;
        }
 }
```

(из `SceneController` здесь удалил всё что было связано с `ButonScript`, что бы лишний раз не смущать народ)

Не получается у меня именно присвоить кнопке значение одной из появившейся карты. Либо присваивается звук любой карты из всего массива карт, либо первой появившейся карты, либо последней карты.

Вопросы:

1. правильно ли я думаю, что нужно создать новый массив, который будет хранить id сгенерированных карт и уже из него рандомно присваивать значение для id `ButtonScript`.
2. как создать такой массив?
3. как рандомно присвоить значение из этого массива? Нужно ли применять метод перемешивания как в скрипте выше или есть более простой способ?

Comment: связанный вопрос: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/547996/213987

Comment: Спс, с перемешиванием все понятно, но как мне получить массив из индексов созданных карт?

Comment: Сгенерируйте карты в массив карт, перемешайте, возьмите первые три карты в новый массив. (Я думаю, что массив карт предпочительнее массива id карт)

Comment: @A K подскажите пожалуйста как создать такой массив. Я пробовал так: `List<int> numberVoices = new List<int>();
                for (int a=0; a<3; a++)
                {
                    numberVoices.Add(index);

                }` пробовал так: `int[] numberVoces = new int[3];
 
            for (int a = 0; a < numberVoeces.Length; a++)
            {
                        numberVoces[a] = numbers[index];                 
            }` В дебаг логе по чему то получаю `id кнопкиSystem.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Int32]`