# Создание Рандома БЕЗ повторяющихся объектов

Tags: c#, случайные-числа, switch, case

.Здравствуйте, добрые люди. Передо мной стоит задача, рандомно определить количество, так называемых выживших и перечислить их. Проблема заключается в том, что сами имена выживших повторяются, то есть мой рандом называет одно число  с  промежутка несколько раз

```
Random rnd = new Random(); //try not to repeat(one goats shouldn't be eatten for 2 times for example)
            int n = rnd.Next(0, 8); //how many survive by Random 
            Console.WriteLine("Выжило {0}, а именно: ", n);
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) //cyrcle with random number of iteration(how many alive?)
            {
                Random rand = new Random();
                int k = rand.Next(1, 7);
            switch (k)
            {
                case 1:

                    Console.WriteLine(Smarty.Name);
                    Console.WriteLine(" Цвет: {0}", Smarty.Color);
                    break;
                case 2:

                    Console.WriteLine(Bunt.Name);
                    Console.WriteLine(" Цвет: {0}", Bunt.Color);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    Console.WriteLine(Stomp.Name);
                    Console.WriteLine(" Цвет: {0}", Stomp.Color);
                    break;
                case 4:

                    Console.WriteLine(Talker.Name);
                    Console.WriteLine(" Цвет: {0}", Talker.Color);
                    break;
                case 5:
                    Console.WriteLine(Scum.Name);
                    Console.WriteLine(" Цвет: {0}", Scum.Color);
                    break;
                case 6:
                    Console.WriteLine(Teaser.Name);
                    Console.WriteLine(" Цвет: {0}", Teaser.Color);
                    break;
                case 7:
                    Console.WriteLine(Lil.Name);
                    Console.WriteLine(" Цвет: {0}", Lil.Color);
                    break;
                default:
                    Console.WriteLine("Таких у нас нету");
                    break;
            }
        }`
```

Соответственно хочется чтобы один кейс срабатывал только по одному разу. Была идея создать List с последующим удалением выбранного рандомом обьекта, но не получилось. Буду рад услышать варианты ваших решений. Спасибо.

Comment: А в чем хранятся ваши выжившие? Мне кажется вам подойдет ответ на [этот вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2019417/how-to-access-random-item-in-list)

Comment: Полный дубликат канонического вопроса о перемешивании готового массива: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/547996/213987 Просто берёте ваш массив выживших (без повторов, раз вам так надо) и применяете тасование Фишера–Йетса

Comment: @nonForgivingJesus элемент массива - это экземпляр класса.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Идея с list довольно таки неплохая. И switch/case не обязательно использовать.

```
        // Создание списка выживших
        List<string> alives = new List<string> { "Tom", "Sendi", "Rassel", "Mike", "Emma", "Olivia", "Mia", "Ethan" };

        Console.WriteLine("Welcome to dead game!\nNames players:\n");

        // Вывод списка на екран
        foreach (string player in alives)
        {
            Console.Write("{0}  ", player);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("\nStart game!");

        Random rand = new Random();
        int next;
        // Убийство наших вишывших
        do
        {
            next = rand.Next(0, alives.Count);

            Console.WriteLine("Dead is - {0}", alives[next]);

            alives.RemoveAt(next);
        } while (alives.Count != 1);

        Console.WriteLine("Winner is a {0}", alives[0]);
```

Результат

```
Welcome to dead game!
Names players:

Tom  Sendi  Rassel  Mike  Emma  Olivia  Mia  Ethan
Start game!
Dead is - Olivia
Dead is - Mike
Dead is - Rassel
Dead is - Tom
Dead is - Sendi
Dead is - Emma
Dead is - Ethan
Winner is a Mia
```

Comment: Данное решение подработал под свой код и всё заработало как должно было у меня в фантазиях, да и идея решения была примерно такова, как ваша, просто руки пока не оттуда, чтобы все без багов реализовать :) Спасибо вам огромное!

Comment: @MaxSquirrel: так лучше не делать. Представьте, что у Вас миллион значений. Вы представляете, сколько раз и в каком количестве придётся перетаскивать блоки памяти из-за удалений в листе? Единственный адекватный вариант - сгенерировать последовательность от 0 до N-1 и просто перемешать ее

Comment: @Kir_Antipov, согласен. Моё решение является затратным по ресурсам, чем вариант becouse. Но данная задача проста и в ней явно не подразумевается миллион значений.

Answer (score 2):

Можно создать массив ключей и перемешать их.

Также хорошо поместить всех людей в массив для удобства обработки.

```
   int[] keys =  {1,2,3,4,5,6,7};
   personType[] person = {Smarty,Bunt,Stomp,Talker, Scum, Teaser, Lil};
   for (i=1; i<10; i++){
     int t = rand.Next(0, 6);
     int s = rand.Next(0, 6);
     swap(keys[t],keys[s]);
   }
   for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
      {
         Console.WriteLine(person[keys[i]].Name);
         Console.WriteLine(" Цвет: {0}", person[keys[i]].Color);
      }
```

Comment: Подскажите, метод Swap как сделать активным, потому как в моей сборке он закрыт и второе: при выводе свойства Name и Color - также не активны.

Comment: Вы не указали тип объектов Smarty и пр. personType вместо него надо написать ваш тип для объектов.

swap подразумевает обмен двух элементов массива местами.

   x=keys[t];

   keys[t]=keys[s];

   keys[s]=x;

Comment: думаю ваш ответ имеет место быть, от меня +1, но я уже нашел другое решение, спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Из коробки такого метода нет. Тебе нужно самому написать класс который будет тебе рандомные имена со списка выдавать.

Скажем, что-то вроде

```
public static class RndNameGenerator
{
    Random static rnd = new Random();
    public static list<string> Gen(list<string> namesBase, int resultCount)
   {
        var namesLst= namesBase.Clone();
        var lstRez = new list<string>(); 

        for(int i=0; i<= resultCount; i++)
        {
            int itemNum = rand.Next(0, namesBase.Count() );
            lstRez.Add(namesLst(itemNum));
            lst.RemoveAt(itemNum);
        }

        return lstRez;
   }
}
```

И обратившись

```
RndNameGenerator.Gen(someNameList, 3);
```

оно вернет 3 ункальных имени. (правда, если в самому someNameList нету дубликатов)

код, конечно же, не проверялся.