# Рандомизация массива префабов. Как удалить одинаковых клонов?

Tags: c#, unity3d, monodevelop

Постановка задачи есть массив префабов

public GameObject[] myArray = new GameObject[6];

В самом юнити я прикрепил к нему 6 префабов.

На сцене есть пустой GameObject CardSpawner
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В начале сцены выбирается 4 случайных префаба из 6

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;



public class ControllerCardHero : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject[] myArray = new GameObject[6];





    void Start () {


        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++  ) {

            int rand = Random.Range (0, myArray.Length);

            Instantiate (myArray [rand], myArray [rand].transform.position, myArray [rand].transform.rotation);




        }



        }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А теперь задача ?

Как убрать повторяющихся клонов. Сделать что каждый из 4 клонов был уникальный???

Comment: просто перетасуйте элементы массива и возьмите первые 4

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/547997/179186

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Не повторяемые числа при цикличной рандомизировании числа в заданном диапазоне?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1028970/%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b2%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d1%8f%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b0-%d0%b2-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bc-%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b5)

Comment: Не нужно плодить дубликаты, если появилась новая информации - дополните свой предыдущий вопрос.

Answer (score 0):

Решил вопрос переделав предложенный скрипт под себя.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;


public class ControllerCardHero : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject[] arrayPrefabCard = new GameObject[6];


    void Start () {

        // перетасовка массива 
        for (int i = 0; i < arrayPrefabCard.Length; i++) {
            int j =  Random.Range ( 0, (i + 1));
            var temp = arrayPrefabCard [j];
            arrayPrefabCard [j] = arrayPrefabCard [i];
            arrayPrefabCard [i] = temp;



        }

        // взять первы 4 елементы массива
        for (int k = 0; k < 4; k++  ) {

            Instantiate (arrayPrefabCard [k], arrayPrefabCard [k].transform.position, arrayPrefabCard [k].transform.rotation);
        }
        }
}
```