# Как заполнить массив, учитывая значение другой переменной?

Tags: c#, массивы, unity3d

Есть массив состоящий из 25 переменных типа int. Нужно заполнить его таким образом, чтобы первые N (N = numberMines) элементов массива равнялись 0, а остальные 1. Далее нужно просто перемешать массив.

```
public int numberMines = 3;
public int[] mines;
public int i = 0;

public void ArrayMines()
{
    for (i=0;i <= numberMines;i++)
    {
        mines[i] = 0;
    }
    for (i=0; numberMines < i <= mines.Length; i++)
    {
        mines[i] = 1;
    }
```

Начало моего кода, который я собирал из нескольких документаций. Я уверен, что тут далеко не одна ошибка, буду рад, если кто-нибудь поможет готовым кодом с объяснением.

Comment: А как Вы пытались решить эту задачу?

Comment: public int numberMines = 3;
    public int[] mines;
    public int i = 0;

    public void ArrayMines()
    {
        for (i=0;i <= numberMines;i++)
        {
            mines[i] = 0;
        }
        for (i=0; numberMines < i <= mines.Length; i++)
        {
            mines[i] = 1;
        }

Comment: А давайте отредактируем вопрос и внесем Ваш вариант туда

Comment: да, конечно, сейчас сделаю

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для начала позволю себе немножко рефакторинга.

Метод `ArrayMines` переименуем в `GetRandomMinesArray`, т.к. название метода нужно начинать с глагола.

`numberMines` переименуем в `_numberMines`. Нижнее подчеркивание будет означать, что это поле будет видимым во всем классе. Поля без подчеркивания могут использоваться внутри методов, соответственно, такое поле будет видимым в пределах метода.

`mines` переименуем в `_minesArray`. Это дело вкуса, но мне так удобнее, когда по имени переменной сразу понятно, что это массив, и какой именно массив.

`public int i = 0;` вообще уберем. Поле i нам не нужно с видимостью по всему классу.

Далее. Поля внутри класса не должны быть public. Это нарушение инкапсуляции. Делаем поля private. Если вдруг нужно дать доступ к полям извне, используйте геттеры и сеттеры.

Теперь код *(самое интересное) =)*

В одном цикле перебираем все элементы и если индекс меньше `_numberMines`, то записываем в этот элемент массива `0`, иначе записываем `1`.

```
        for (int i = 0; i < _minesArray.Length; i++)
        {
            if (i < _numberMines)
            {
                _minesArray[i] = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                _minesArray[i] = 1;
            }
        }
```

На выходе получим нужный нам массив, но без рандомного заполнения.
Осталось рандомизировать.

Для этого воспользуемся [этим примером](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/547996/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B-%D0%B2-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B5).
Алгоритм давно изобретен, в интернете встречается часто.

```
        for (int i = _minesArray.Length - 1; i >= 1; i--)
        {
            int j = random.Next(i + 1);
            var temp = _minesArray[j];
            _minesArray[j] = _minesArray[i];
            _minesArray[i] = temp;
        }
```

Здесь `random` - это экземпляр класса `Random`

Всё! Остается только вернуть результат

```
    return _minesArray
```

Весь класс выглядит так:

```
public class MinesCreator
{
    private int _numberMines = 3;
    private int[] _minesArray = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };


    public int[] GetRandomMinesArray()
    {
        Random random = new Random();

        for (int i = 0; i < _minesArray.Length; i++)
        {
            if (i < _numberMines)
            {
                _minesArray[i] = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                _minesArray[i] = 1;
            }
        }

        for (int i = _minesArray.Length - 1; i >= 1; i--)
        {
            int j = random.Next(i + 1);
            var temp = _minesArray[j];
            _minesArray[j] = _minesArray[i];
            _minesArray[i] = temp;
        }

        return _minesArray;
    }
}
```

Массив здесь проинициализирован цифрами для того, чтобы убедиться, что всё работает как надо. Но инициализировать не обязательно. Массив у меня получился из 10 элементов, Вы просили 25. Но набирать 25 чисел я поленился. Думаю, Вы сами без проблем сможете добавить нужное количество элементов

Проверял в консольном приложении. Для проверки в классе Programm пишем что-то типа вот этого:

```
MinesCreator mines = new MinesCreator();

int[] result = mines.GetRandomMinesArray();

foreach (var item in result)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

P.S. Кстати, Ваш вот этот код

```
for (i=0; numberMines < i <= mines.Length; i++)
```

вообще работать не будет.

Comment: Спасибо огромное за исправления! Буду пробовать!

Comment: `CreateArrayMines` "создать массив мин", но он же не создает никаких массивов, верно? А если метод несколько раз вызвать, то он испортит массив, "созданный" в прошлом вызове, верно? Еще перемешивание можно вынести в отдельный метод.

Comment: @aepot Ну конкретно в нашем случае массив как раз создается внутри метода. Извне мы ему ничего не передаем. А если вызвать несколько раз этот метод, то он несколько раз создаст несколько разных массивов и вернет их.
Разве не так?
Конечно, будет метод создавать или переделывать какой-то один и тот же массив, это уже автор вопроса будет решать в контексте своего приложения

Comment: @disman Пожалуйста

Comment: Да ну? У вас массив в конструкторе класса создается, перечитайте свой собственный код и будьте внимательней.

Comment: @aepot где в конструкторе? Я вообще не использовал конструктор

Comment: @aepot понял Вас. Пардон за споры :) Согласен. Невнимательность...

Comment: В таком случае вы не знаете, как работает инициализация полей, которые вы присваиваете при объявлении. Они неявно инициализируются именно в конструкторе класса при создании. То есть если у вас коде нет конструктора, не значит что его вообще нет.

Comment: _Согласен. Невнимательность_ - так поправьте код тогда, сейчас он выглядит ненадежно.