# Возник вопрос, как вывести 10 имён рандомно, но чтобы они не повторялись?

Tags: c#

```
введите сюда код
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string[] MassNames = (string[])Enum.GetNames(typeof(Names));
        Random random = new Random();
        students people = new students();
        int randomNew = random.Next(0, 10); ///// генерация имен
        people.name = (Names)randomNew; ///// рандом имен
        people.gender = randomNew < 5 ? (Gender)0 : (Gender)1; //// логика на пол - имя

        for (int n = 0; n < MassNames.Length; n++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(people.name + " " + people.gender);
        }


        Console.ReadKey();
    }
    public class students     ////////STUDENTS///////
    {
        public Names name;
        public Gender gender;
        public int age;
    }
    public enum Names
    {
        Oleg, Igor, Vladimir, Aid, Egor, Sonya, Nastya, Olya, Sasha, Marina
    }
    public enum Gender
    {
        Man, Woman
    }

}
```

Comment: Если у вас 10 разных имен и вам нужно получить 10 случайных имен без повторений из указанного набора, проще будет построить массив / список и перемешать его (дубликат: [Как перемешать (случайно переставить) элементы в массиве?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/547996/))

Comment: Спасибо, попробую, то что вы предложии

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%A4%D0%B8%D1%88%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0_%E2%80%94_%D0%99%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D0%B0